# "Охотники - инженер Зубаткин и рабочий Нечаев, гнали зайца по раскисшему осеннему полю"

Tags: пунктуация

"Охотники - инженер Зубаткин и рабочий Нечаев, гнали зайца по раскисшему осеннему полю". Правильно ли я расставил знаки, если нет, то как будет правильно и почему? Дайте ссылку на правила

Comment: А на основании каких правил вы-то расставляли знаки?

Comment: Никаких, расставил интуитивно. Вот хотелось бы узнать правило

Comment: А ваша интуиция не подсказала вам, что одиночной запятой между подлежащим и сказуемым не бывает?

Comment: Что-то в конце фразы бывает и быть обязано, ну и тире имеет отличие от дефиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Охотники, **инженер Зубаткин и рабочий Нечаев**, гнали зайца по раскисшему осеннему полю.*

Это тема обособленных приложений, в данном случае **обособление запятыми наиболее приемлемо.**

У Розенталя:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

1. Обособляется распространенное приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному существительному: Старуха, Тришкина мать, умерла, но старики, **отец и тесть**, были ещё живы (С.-Щ);

**Примечание**

1) У Розенталя указан  еще вариант без обособления по образцу: 4) если при определяемом существительном имеются **два нераспространенных приложения, соединенных союзом и**: *студенты филологи и журналисты; депутаты консерваторы и либералы*;

Тогда получится: *Охотники **инженер Зубаткин и рабочий Нечаев** гнали зайца по раскисшему осеннему полю.*

2) Еще один  вариант — это обособление с помощью тире, такая конструкция ближе к присоединительной, произношение с увеличенной паузой: *Охотники — **инженер Зубаткин и рабочий Нечаев** — гнали зайца по раскисшему осеннему полю.*